# wpf Change IsEnabled property of Button control and Text property of TextBlock which placed inside the Button control

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers

I have a `Button` control inside a `DataTemplate` for my `ListBoxItem` with a `TextBlock` inside it:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SomeitemTempate">
....
<Button x:Name="nxBut" Margin="20,0,20,20" Height="30" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" FontSize="16" Background="White" Click="nxBut_Click">
     <TextBlock x:Name="nxBut_Txt" Text="Some Button" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FF11700C"/>
</Button>
....
```

Now when user clicked the `Button`, I want to change `IsEnabled` property of the button to `False`, and the `Text` of the `TextBlock` to "Clicked". After googling for some times, i modified it:

```
    ....
    <DataTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=nxBut, Path=IsPressed}" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="nxBut" Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
            <Setter TargetName="nxBut_Txt" Property="Text" Value="Clicked"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </DataTemplate.Triggers>
</DataTemplate>
```

But it does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would swap your Button for ToggleButton and bind your isenabled to ischecked, and you don't really need the TextBlock in there it looks like.

Comment: @Chris If i change it with Tooglebutton, does that mean if i click it once again, the button will be enabled again? if so, then i dont want it :/

Comment: Not unless you manually revert back the bool on IsEnabled. It would be something like `<ToggleButton IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Converter="{StaticResource InvertedBoolConverter"}}"/>` So once it's clicked, that's it, it's disabled, until it is somehow reset be it manually or if a screen re-renders or something. Not sure of your requirements but you could save the bool if it needs to stay persistent. Your Inverted bool converter on it will just make it so IF IsChecked=True, THEN IsEnabled=False

Comment: @ChrisW. Im still not familiar yet with `Converter` stuff. I wrote "if ((bool)value == true) { return false; } return true;" When i click the button an error occured :(

Comment: Give "wpf inverted boolean converter" a quick google, there's tons of tutorials. :)

Comment: @ChrisW. lol i already do that before u commented :D Thank you now it works perfectly! btw, why u dont write ur answer so i can mark it as answer? :)

Comment: Oh cool! Glad you found your remedy. Yea I don't normally put stuff as answers when I think it's a quick like one sentence helper or haven't tested. Guess I will though, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So like discussed. If we just swap `Button` for `ToggleButton` and bind to `IsEnabled` to `IsChecked` of itself. Then upon press it will just disable itself until it's manually reset by other means. Something like;

```
<ToggleButton IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, 
                                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
                                  Converter="{StaticResource InvertedBoolConverter"}}"/>
```

While using an inverted boolean converter to swap True for False or vice versa on the IsEnabled property based on IsChecked. Since once you click it once, it's now disabled, the user won't be able to to uncheck the ToggleButton anyway. Hope this helps.

Comment: you said that it is possible to save the boolean value, how?

Comment: Another quick google search for something like "saving settings" or "saving values" for wpf should give you some tutorials on how to do like Blah.Save() and show you some best practices. :)

Comment: Oh and of course if you run into specific issues implementing it, just ask a separate question on here. Lots of folks ready to help!

Comment: Yea I think i will do that but not now. I will try it by myself first :)